# DateTimeFormatter и Calendar

Tags: java

Как можно задать дату,используя DateTimeFormatter и Calendar?
Задаю следующим образом:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
DateTimeFormatter dateFormat=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("DD-MM-YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Не понимаю как правильно распарсить строку str,используя DateTimeFormatter,чтобы закинуть в Calendar.Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю верно ли понял вопрос. Но вот вариант, хотя по факту можно различными способами этого добиться:

```
    // example input string "25-07-1993 01:00:00"
    public Calendar parseDateString(String date) {
        
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatter);

        int dayOfMonth = localDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
        int month = localDateTime.getMonthValue();
        int year = localDateTime.getYear();
        int hour = localDateTime.getHour();
        int minute = localDateTime.getMinute();
        int second = localDateTime.getSecond();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth, hour, minute, second);
        
        return calendar;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее!

Comment: Рад помочь, но не все так сложно. Вам просто следует чуток больше времени уделить исследованию стандартных джавовских классов для работы с датами и временем и вы бы нашли методы, которые помогли преобразовать одно в другое.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, вы говорите об этом

```
SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date(1212121212121L); // числа условные

System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```

Comment: Советую ознакомится с этой статьёй https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1941-kak-ne-poterjatjhsja-vo-vremeni--datetime-i-calendar

Comment: К сожалению,нет,речь не об этом.У меня на входных данных метода строка(дата).Метод возвращает тип Calendar. Ограничение по библиотекам: использование библиотеки Calendar и DateTimeFormatter